# Using "select feature" to show sum of attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

Is there a way to show the sum of certain attributes of the selected features?

for example, I'm selecting several buildings each having a number of users, selecting the buildings only shows their number, and what I do is copy the data and paste them into an excel sheet and then use an autosum formula to obtain the result.

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Activate `Statistics Panel` by clicking on `Show Statistical Summary` (a big sigma button), or `View | Panels | Statistics Panel`.

After selecting your Buildings layer and attribute field, tick on `Selected feature only` at the bottom.

Comment: This is what i was looking for ... i just searched a bit more and found how to make the sum function for the desired attribute ..thank you

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Just if you find any of these (15 or 16 statistics by default) unnecessary, please click on the small ellipsis (dot-dot-dot) button at the lower-right corner. You can select items you need.